# Need to Fetch data from external API (without storing at database) and show data on multiple views

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have few custom modules created using Module Builder. I need to fetch data using external REST API (around 200-300k record per API) and without storing data in suite database I need to display data on custom modules (using UI provided by SuiteCRM only. NO CUSTOM UI). and also I have operations to be perform on data which will again call External API.

So, as per requirement, Data should not be saved at database. How to achieve this in SUITECRM (7.11.8 version)?
 I have tried using Process record hook. But things aren't working.

Comment: Process record hook run using records in the module and if there is no record then it will not execute.

Comment: You can't really display data into OOTB list, edit or detail view without saving in the database because those are bonded to DB manager class.
One quick question, you can't save anything in the SuiteCRM? What about saving any unique/primary key of every record? You can't save that as well?

Comment: We can save that primary Key. But then how can I accomplish my task with That?

Comment: If you can't save data in SuiteCRM and require to fetch it on run-time then list view data fetching will take very much time(depending on the number of records)